# java.net.SocketTimeoutException Exception in WebServices (SOAP/CXF)

Tags: java, web-services, soap, cxf

I am writing a webservice with CXF. But I am getting `SocketTimeOutException`. But I am unable to debug where it coming from. It says which WebService is failing. But not saying why. I have the timeouts fairly high. 8 minutes in milliseconds. But still i get the error. I am guessing the problem is elsewhere.

The stacktrace is:

```
[3/26/21 0:10:42:137 IST] 00000113 SystemErr     R Caused by: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: SocketTimeoutException invoking http://XXXXXXXXX:9080/GTC/services/ProcessGtcOrderSoapHttpPort?wsdl: Read timed out
[3/26/21 0:10:42:137 IST] 00000113 SystemErr     R  at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
[3/26/21 0:10:42:137 IST] 00000113 SystemErr     R  at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:83)
[3/26/21 0:10:42:138 IST] 00000113 SystemErr     R  at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
[3/26/21 0:10:42:138 IST] 00000113 SystemErr     R  at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:437)
[3/26/21 0:10:42:138 IST] 00000113 SystemErr     R  at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPConduit$WrappedOutputStream.mapException(HTTPConduit.java:1402)
[3/26/21 0:10:42:139 IST] 00000113 SystemErr     R  at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPConduit$WrappedOutputStream.close(HTTPConduit.java:1386)
[3/26/21 0:10:42:139 IST] 00000113 SystemErr     R  at org.apache.cxf.transport.AbstractConduit.close(AbstractConduit.java:56)
[3/26/21 0:10:42:139 IST] 00000113 SystemErr     R  at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPConduit.close(HTTPConduit.java:673)
[3/26/21 0:10:42:139 IST] 00000113 SystemErr     R  at org.apache.cxf.interceptor.MessageSenderInterceptor$MessageSenderEndingInterceptor.handleMessage(MessageSenderInterceptor.java:63)
[3/26/21 0:10:42:140 IST] 00000113 SystemErr     R  at org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain.doIntercept(PhaseInterceptorChain.java:308)
[3/26/21 0:10:42:140 IST] 00000113 SystemErr     R  at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.doInvoke(ClientImpl.java:532)
[3/26/21 0:10:42:140 IST] 00000113 SystemErr     R  at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.invoke(ClientImpl.java:441)
[3/26/21 0:10:42:140 IST] 00000113 SystemErr     R  at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.invoke(ClientImpl.java:356)
[3/26/21 0:10:42:141 IST] 00000113 SystemErr     R  at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.invoke(ClientImpl.java:314)
[3/26/21 0:10:42:141 IST] 00000113 SystemErr     R  at org.apache.cxf.frontend.ClientProxy.invokeSync(ClientProxy.java:96)
[3/26/21 0:10:42:141 IST] 00000113 SystemErr     R  at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.JaxWsClientProxy.invoke(JaxWsClientProxy.java:140)
[3/26/21 0:10:42:142 IST] 00000113 SystemErr     R  ... 2 more
[3/26/21 0:10:42:142 IST] 00000113 SystemErr     R Caused by: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out
[3/26/21 0:10:42:142 IST] 00000113 SystemErr     R  at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)
[3/26/21 0:10:42:143 IST] 00000113 SystemErr     R  at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead(SocketInputStream.java:127)
[3/26/21 0:10:42:143 IST] 00000113 SystemErr     R  at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:182)
[3/26/21 0:10:42:143 IST] 00000113 SystemErr     R  at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:152)
[3/26/21 0:10:42:143 IST] 00000113 SystemErr     R  at java.io.BufferedInputStream.fill(BufferedInputStream.java:257)
[3/26/21 0:10:42:144 IST] 00000113 SystemErr     R  at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read1(BufferedInputStream.java:297)
[3/26/21 0:10:42:144 IST] 00000113 SystemErr     R  at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(BufferedInputStream.java:356)
[3/26/21 0:10:42:144 IST] 00000113 SystemErr     R  at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.parseHTTPHeader(HttpClient.java:766)
[3/26/21 0:10:42:145 IST] 00000113 SystemErr     R  at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.parseHTTP(HttpClient.java:709)
[3/26/21 0:10:42:145 IST] 00000113 SystemErr     R  at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(HttpURLConnection.java:1605)
[3/26/21 0:10:42:145 IST] 00000113 SystemErr     R  at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1510)
[3/26/21 0:10:42:146 IST] 00000113 SystemErr     R  at java.net.HttpURLConnection.getResponseCode(HttpURLConnection.java:491)
[3/26/21 0:10:42:146 IST] 00000113 SystemErr     R  at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.URLConnectionHTTPConduit$URLConnectionWrappedOutputStream$2.run(URLConnectionHTTPConduit.java:377)
[3/26/21 0:10:42:146 IST] 00000113 SystemErr     R  at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.URLConnectionHTTPConduit$URLConnectionWrappedOutputStream$2.run(URLConnectionHTTPConduit.java:373)
[3/26/21 0:10:42:146 IST] 00000113 SystemErr     R  at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:734)
[3/26/21 0:10:42:146 IST] 00000113 SystemErr     R  at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.URLConnectionHTTPConduit$URLConnectionWrappedOutputStream.getResponseCode(URLConnectionHTTPConduit.java:373)
[3/26/21 0:10:42:146 IST] 00000113 SystemErr     R  at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPConduit$WrappedOutputStream.doProcessResponseCode(HTTPConduit.java:1599)
[3/26/21 0:10:42:147 IST] 00000113 SystemErr     R  at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPConduit$WrappedOutputStream.handleResponseInternal(HTTPConduit.java:1627)
[3/26/21 0:10:42:147 IST] 00000113 SystemErr     R  at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPConduit$WrappedOutputStream.handleResponse(HTTPConduit.java:1572)
[3/26/21 0:10:42:147 IST] 00000113 SystemErr     R  at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPConduit$WrappedOutputStream.close(HTTPConduit.java:1373)
[3/26/21 0:10:42:147 IST] 00000113 SystemErr     R  ... 12 more
```

I am setting the timeouts as:

```
getBindingProvider().getRequestContext().put(BindingProviderProperties.CONNECT_TIMEOUT, connectTimeout);
getBindingProvider().getRequestContext().put(BindingProviderProperties.REQUEST_TIMEOUT, connectTimeout);
getBindingProvider().getRequestContext().put(BindingProvider.ENDPOINT_ADDRESS_PROPERTY, endPointUrl);
```

`connectTimeout` is set to 480000.

Is there anyway I can debug this? Any pointers would be helpful.

Comment: Where are you making the call from? Can you connect to the machine that runs the SOAP client and open `http://XXXXXXXXX:9080/GTC/services/ProcessGtcOrderSoapHttpPort?wsdl` in a browser there, or can you do a telnet to XXXXXXXXX on port 9080 to see if things timeout also?

Comment: @Bogdan I need some help on this one. A friend on mine suggested I use `getBindingProvider().getRequestContext().put("javax.xml.ws.client.receiveTimeout", connectTimeout);
  getBindingProvider().getRequestContext().put("javax.xml.ws.client.connectionTimeout", connectTimeout);` And to my surprise it did. But I am baffled as to how. A little explanation would be helpful.

Comment: Maybe it's because the properties aren't standardized between implementations ([see for ex this](https://github.com/javaee/metro-jax-ws/issues/1166)). Just out of curiosity, how long does the call take?

Comment: Thanks for the link. It is a surprise that it still isn't standardized. It is being called from a lot of places... the worst case scenario would still be not more than 40 seconds.